# Copy and paste value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code on the internet that collects data from sheet 3 to the very end one, then combines data to sheet "STOCK DETAILS".
The problem is I just want to paste all the data as value.
I'm new to excel VBA so please help me! Many thanks!

So this is the code:

```
Sub Combine2()
Dim J As Long, lstrw As Long, lstco As Long, lstrw2 As Long
Dim sTableName As String

    'Define Variables
sTableName = "Table1"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
On Error Resume Next
Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").ListObjects(sTableName).Delete
Sheets(3).Rows(1).Copy Destination:=Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").Range("A4")
    For J = 3 To Sheets.Count    ' from sheet 2 to last sheet
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets(J).Cells) > 0 Then
            With Sheets(J)
                lstrw = .Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                lstco = .Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column
                lstrw2 = Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
                .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lstrw, lstco)).Copy Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").Range("A" & lstrw2)(2)
            End With
        End If

    Next
    With Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").ListObjects.Add(xlSrcRange, Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").Range("A$4:$L$9999"), , xlYes)
   .Name = "Table1"
   .TableStyle = "TableStyleLight21"
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To paste just the values you use

```
.Range(...).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thanks for helping me. I've tried this but it didn't work:
Sheets(3).Rows(1).Copy
Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").Range("A4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Comment: I think I should add some codes here, but until now I haven't found where I how to
".Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(lstrw, lstco)).Copy Sheets("STOCK DETAILS").Range("A" & lstrw2)(2)"

Comment: I really appreciate your help! This is my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LX8a6cSWtMo9FHpKd6txH_bjev86nnMr/view?usp=sharing